# Codename One - Automatic sizing an image according to the available space

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I have a logo in the top of a login screen:

```
ScaleImageLabel logo =  new ScaleImageLabel(theme.getImage("myLogo.svg"))
logo.setName("MyLogo");
logo.setUIID("MyLogo");
backgroundContainer.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(logo));
```

My main problem is the sizing, because on some devices is too big, on other devices is too small.

For example, suppose that I want that the logo resizes automatically at the maximum the 80% of the horizontal screen space and at the maximum the 20% of the vertical space (according to what is the largest value of them). How can I achieve this if the logo is in the North of a Border Layout?

Comment: in xml android:weight works like width, height percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shai's answer is correct in general, but in this particular case I need more precision and control on image size, that should change automatically according to the screen available size (in other words, the logo size should change on device orientation and when the virtual keyboard is used). Note that I'm using a vectorial image to avoid problems of loss of image quality on resizing (I tested that this SVG file is rendered correctly on Android 4, so I suppose that is rendered correctly on any modern device).

I share my solution:

```
public class MyMainClass {

    [...]
    private static Label logo;

    public void init(Object context) {
        [...]
    }

    public void start() {
        [...]

        // Insert vectorial logo in the north
        // Constraints:
        // logoMaxWidth is the maximum horizontal screen space in percentage
        // logoMaxHeight is the maximum vertical screen space in percentage
        double logoMaxWidth = 0.75;
        double logoMaxHeight = 0.15;
        logo = new Label((theme.getImage("Logo.svg")).scaledSmallerRatio(Double.valueOf(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() * logoMaxWidth).intValue(), Double.valueOf(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() * logoMaxHeight).intValue()));
        backgroundContainer.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(logo));

        [...]

        // Recalculate the size of the logo when device size changes
        Form logoForm = logo.getComponentForm();
        if (logoForm != null) {
            logoForm.addSizeChangedListener(l -> {
                logo.remove();
                logo = new Label((theme.getImage("Logo.svg")).scaledSmallerRatio(Double.valueOf(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() * logoMaxWidth).intValue(), Double.valueOf(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() * logoMaxHeight).intValue()));
                backgroundContainer.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(logo));
                logoForm.revalidate();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using flow layout to wrap the component. Flow layout gives the component its preferred size so your scaling component no longer matters if the preferred size is too small.

I would suggest using a multi-image that looks decent in all devices based on DPI and avoiding scaling for an element like a logo. Multi-image was designed exactly for this purpose. Alternatively you can size the image in millimeters using code like:

```
Image img = logo.scaledHeight(Display.getInstance().convert(sizeInMM));
```